# Page title and body field of specific page

Tags: 8, theming

I have a page--front.html.twig file. I can't figure out how to show a specific node title and body summary on the frontpage with only using twig. I know I can create a view of something like that and show it with: `{{ drupal_view('viewmachinename', 'blockname') }}`, but in my opinion it's a little bit overkill for just showing the title and body of specific node.

Normally I show the current node title and body summary with `{{ node.label }}` and `{{node.body.summary}}`, but I don't know how to show the page title and body summary with an other nid.

I try to show the page title and body summary with `nid 2` on the frontpage.

Comment: Are you doing this just to learn twig? If not then you can configure which node is shown on the front page in Configuration > System > Basic site settings. Enter `/node/2` in the Front page field.

Comment: Yes I know, but page `node 2` is not my front page. It has content which should be displayed at the frontpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this in twig only, you can use the [drupal_field()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#drupal-field) function provided by the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

For example, to print the title of node 2:

```
{{ drupal_field('title', 'node', 2) }}
```

Or to print the body field for node 2 using the field's configuration from the teaser view mode:

```
{{ drupal_field('body', 'node', 2, 'teaser') }}
```

Or to print an image field with custom formatter settings:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 2, {type: 'image_url', settings: {image_style: 'large'}}) }}
```

I'd probably aim to create a custom view mode here and then print the whole view mode as one chunk with the [drupal_entity()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#drupal-entity) function. For example:

```
{{ drupal_entity('node', 2, 'my_custom_view_mode') }}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfect!